# Spring placeholder doesn't resolve properties in JavaConfig

Tags: java, spring, properties-file, spring-java-config

Currently i have a Spring xml configuration (Spring 4) which load a properties file.

context.properties

```
my.app.service = myService
my.app.other = ${my.app.service}/sample
```

Spring xml configuration

```
<bean id="contextProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
    <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true" />
    <property name="fileEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:context.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="placeholder" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true" />
    <property name="properties" ref="contextProperties" />
    <property name="nullValue" value="@null" />
    <property name="systemPropertiesModeName" value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE" />
</bean>
```

Bean which use the properties

```
@Component
public class MyComponent {

    @Value("${my.app.other}")
    private String others;

}
```

This works perfectly and the `others` value is `MyService/sample`, as excepted. But when i try to replace this configuration by a JavaConfig, the `@Value` in my component doesn't works in the same way. the value isn't `myService/sample` but `${my.app.service}/sample`.

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource(name="contextProperties", ignoreResourceNotFound=true, value={"classpath:context.properties"})
public class PropertiesConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public static PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer placeholder() throws IOException {
        PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer placeholder = new PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer();
        placeholder.setNullValue("@null");
        placeholder.setSystemPropertiesMode(PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE);
        return placeholder;
    }

}
```

Did i miss something in the conversion from xml to Javaconfig ?

ps : I also try to instantiate a `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` instead of a `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` without more success.

Comment: Even if it don't solve your problem, I can confirm that you should use  `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer`, not `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`

Comment: Do the `my.app.service` property resolve fine ? Check with a `@Value("${my.app.service}")`, I wander if the problem comes from the property nesting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update to use configure `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer`. Just having `@PropertySource` annotation will not be sufficient:

```
@Bean
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer properties() {
    return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
}
```

`@PropertySource` annotation does not automatically register a `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` with Spring. Hence we need to explicitly configure `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer`

Below JIRA ticket has more information on the rationale behind this design:

https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-8539

**UPDATE:**
Created simple Spring boot application to use nested properties. It is working fine with the above configuration.

https://github.com/mgooty/property-configurer/tree/master/complete

Comment: I think the OP already did that, and it didn't work, see his 'ps' in the question. I wander if the problem seems to be related with the property nesting (`my.app.other = ${my.app.service}/sample`)

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to import PropertyPlaceholderAutoConfiguration.class.

```
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.PropertyPlaceholderAutoConfiguration;

@Import(PropertyPlaceholderAutoConfiguration.class)
```

The annotation includes a PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer in the context if it doesn't exist.